On defining non-positively curved groups
I am a newbie in the field of geometric group theory, and while reading Nima Hoda's article, "Strongly shortcut spaces", I faced the following sentence which I could not fully grasp.
"However, while the case of negatively curved
groups has been satisfactorily unfied by Gromov's seminal work on hyperbolic
groups, to this date there is no satisfactory general notion of a
nonpositively curved group."
I want to know what the obstruction is, in defining non-positively curved group in an analogous manner to that of hyperbolic groups.
I apologize in advance if the question is not well formulated, and thanks in advance.

There are several well-known notions of nonpositive curvature for groups, for instance, semihyperbolity, automaticity, CAT(0) groups. The author is not entirely honest here.

I appreciate your help! :~)

There is no obstruction to defining non-positively curved groups. Instead, the problem is that there are too many choices for the definition. The author lists several possible definitions in the sentence just preceding the one that you quoted, but there is no general notion of nonpositively curved group which incorporates all of those possibilities (other than saying something silly like "we define a nonpositively curved group to be this or that or the other thing
...").
By contrast, there is one general notion of negatively curved group, namely those finitely generated groups for which the word metric is $\delta$-hyperbolic (for some $\delta \ge 0$). This one general notion does incorporate many special types of hyperbolic groups.

Thanks a lot! :~)
